# Force experienced by magnetic dipole from a current wire loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

I'm trying to figure out how I can calculate the force experienced by an object that has a magnetic moment from a circular loop of wire carrying a current $I$.

The loop of radius $R$ is located at the origin and has the axis of symmetry parallel to the $z$-axis.

I first calculated the classic $z$-component magnetic field using the Biot Savart Law:
$$B_z = \frac{\mu _0}{2}\frac{IR^2}{(z^2+R^2)^{3/2}}$$

Now the object has magnetic moment $\vec{m}$ and is located on the $z$-axis with the moment being parallel to the one of the wire loop. To obtain the force experienced by this object, I used the following formula:

$$\vec{F} = \vec{\nabla}(\vec{m} . \vec{B_z})$$

The magnetic field and moment are parallel thus:
$$\vec{F} = \vec{\nabla}(\frac{m\mu _0 IR^2}{2(z^2+R^2)^{3/2}})=-\frac{3}{2}\frac{m\mu _0 IR^2}{2}\frac{z}{(z^2+R^2)^{5/2}}$$

If the object is at $z_1$, I just replace $z$ by $z_1$.

Is this correct and if not where did I go wrong?

Many thanks!